# Illegal instruction(core dumped) error on Jetson Nano

Tags: python, nvidia-jetson-nano

Sorry if my description is long and boring but I want to give you most important details to solve my problem.
Recently I bought a Jetson Nano Developer Kit with 4Gb of RAM, finally!, and in order to get, which I consider, the best configuration for object detection I am following this guide made by Adrian Rosebrock from Pyimagesearch:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/03/25/how-to-configure-your-nvidia-jetson-nano-for-computer-vision-and-deep-learning/ Date:March, 2020.
A summary of this guide is the following:

- 1: Flash Jetson Pack 4.2 .img inside a microSD for Jetson Nano(mine is 32GB 'A' Class)
- 2: Once inserted on the Nano board, configure Ubuntu 18.04 and get rid of Libreoffice entirely to get more available space
- 3: Step #5: Install system-level dependencies( Including cmake, python3, and nano editor)
- 4: Update CMake (without any errors)
- 5: Install OpenCV system-level dependencies and other development dependencies
- 6: Set up Python virtual environments on your Jetson Nano( succesfully installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper without errors including the bash file edition with nano)
- 7: Create virtaul env with python 3 and install protobuf and libprotobuf to get an more efficient Tensorflow. Succesfully installed. It took an hour to finish, that's normal
- 8: Here comes the headbreaker: install numpy and cython inside this env and check it importing numpy library
  When I try to do this step I get:
  Illegal instruction(core dumped) as you can see in the image:
  [Error with Python3.6.9]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAZhm.png

I said, well let's continue with this tutorial anyway:

- 9: Install Scipy v1.3.3: everything is ok with first three lines, but when I have to use python to execute the stup.py file, IT shows up again(not the clown).
  [Can't execute this line either]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFmnt.jpg

Then I ran an experiment, I have created this "p2cv4" env with Python 2, installed numpy and tested it:
[With Python 2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCWif.png

I can exit() whenever I want and execute other lines that use python
So I concluded that is a python version issue. When I want to execute any python code, terminal ends the program with core dumping, apt-get or pip DO NOT show any errors. And I want to use python 3 because someday in the future a package or library will require python 3.

For python 3 last version for the Jetson Nano is 3.6.9, and idk which version was currently active in March, 2020, like the one Adrian used at that time

In other posts I read that this SIGILL appears when a package or library version like Numpy of TF is not friendly anymore with a specific old or low power CPU, like in this posts:
[Illegal hardware instruction when trying to import tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327879/illegal-hardware-instruction-when-trying-to-import-tensorflow), https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9532

So I want to downgrade to a older python version like 3.6.5 or 3.5 but I can't find clear steps to do so in Ubuntu. I thinks this will fix this error and let me continue with configurations on the Jetson Nano.

The pyimageseach guide uses Python 3.6 but it do not specifies if is last 3.6.9 or another. If is not python causing this error let me know. HELP please!

Comment: Generally speaking, an "illegal instruction" error tends to happen when attempting to run something compiled for 1 CPU architecture on a platform with a different architecture. The architectures don't even have to be that different; I've seen that happen when the CPU architectures were slightly different versions of x86-64.

Comment: Jetson Nano comes with a Quad-core ARM Cortex-A57 MPCore processor and it's the same that shows up in his tutorial. Can python version change so many config that worked well in the past? Because he uses 3.6 too but don't know if is 3.6.9(as I have)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this very same problem following the same guide.  BTW, in this scenario, numpy worked just fine in python when NOT in a virtualenv.  GDB pointed to a problem in libopenblas.

My solution was to start from scratch with a fresh image of jetson-nano-4gb-jp441-sd-card-image.zip and repeat that guide without using virtualenv.  More than likely you are the sole developer on that Nano and can live without virtualenv.

I have followed these guides with success:
https://qengineering.eu/install-opencv-4.5-on-jetson-nano.html

**Skip the virtualenv portions**
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/05/06/getting-started-with-the-nvidia-jetson-nano/

I found this to also be required at this point: "..install the official Jetson Nano TensorFlow by.."

```
ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h
```

Once I made that symbolic link I was able to proceed with the rest of the guide (minus virtualenv) and I managed to not break numpy.

This is not ideal, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 64):

## The 'illegal instruction' could be due to an recent change in the getauxval(AT_HWCAP).

An attempt to read cpuid information from /sys/devices in the event that getauxval did not succeed. (OpenBLAS PRs 2952 and 3004)

export OPENBLAS_CORETYPE=ARMV8 (or whatever the actual hardware is) before launching python should hopefully get around this. For example:

```bash
OPENBLAS_CORETYPE=ARMV8 python
```

If you would like to make this export permanent, you should open your .bashrc file by typing on the terminal:

```bash
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Afterwards, just add "export OPENBLAS_CORETYPE=ARMV8" to the bottom of your .bashrc file, save/exit and reboot your system:

```bash
export OPENBLAS_CORETYPE=ARMV8
```

for more details look at:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/18131
https://www.reddit.com/r/JetsonNano/comments/ktcyoh/illegal_instructioncore_dumped_error_on_jetson/

Answer (score 18):

Installing the correct numpy version helped me resolve this issue. Whenever i imported torch, cv2 or torchvision, I got the error saying Illegal instruction(core dumped).
Use the command `pip install numpy==1.19.4`  and I hope the error goes.

Comment: Downgrading ```numpy``` from ```1.19.5``` to ```1.19.4``` solved the ```Illegal instruction (core dumped)``` error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It worked for me.
I tested it with pyenv environment with python 3.7.9 and gcc-8.4 on Jetson nano (the very first version). Just remember because it compiles everything, it's gonna take a lot longer than just downloading the binaries. (because of `--no-binary`)

```bash
python3 -m pip install -U numpy --no-cache-dir --no-binary numpy
```

You can update your gcc, because default gcc is 7. I am not sure if it does not work with gcc-7.

```bash
sudo apt install gcc-8 g++-8
sudo rm /usr/bin/gcc
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-8 /usr/bin/gcc

sudo rm /usr/bin/g++
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-8 /usr/bin/g++
```

Now to confirm, you can check the version with

```bash
gcc --version
g++ --version
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this a bug with Jetson Nano B01 model.

Yesterday I realized that my Nano is a different model than the one Adrian is showing in his guide(A02).

Thank you doommonkey to lead me to a different guide that looks pretty much to the pyimagesearch tutorial and more recent one (Dec, 2020), I really appreciate that.

I will test it today and if I can build my opencv to functional including Tensorflow. I think this is a half solved problem.

It's a shame that virtualenv is giving this awful error for python 3.6.9. In th is particular model. I tried with venv module too and it can't even install numpy so no virtual env for now

Answer (score -1):

No you can do with the `virtualenv`:

1. remove all numpy ref in the site packages of the virtual environement.
2. upgrade numpy
3. link numpy folder to venv numpy.

Assuming your virtualenv is called ML:

1. ```sh
   cd ~/.virtualenvs/ML/lib/python3.6/site-packages 
   sudo rm -r numpy*
   ```
2. ```sh
   #outside VE:
   deactivate
   sudo pip install --upgrade numpy
   ```
3. ```sh
   #find path to numpy usig pysearchmethod :
   #use pip uninstall numpy, and answer NO, but note. path
   sudo pip uninstall numpy
   #gives me /home/pierre/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy
   cd ~/.virtualenvs/ML/lib/python3.6/site-packages
   ln -s /home/pierre/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy numpy
   ```

Then you can test it:

```sh
workon ML
python -c 'import numpy'
```

If you get stuff related to permission on `/.cache/pip`, you can try to change permission of the folder:

```sh
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.cache/pip
```

If this still doesn't work, try uninstalling numpy on the machine, then re installing it:

```sh
sudo pip uninstall numpy
#Yousof
pip install -U numpy --no-cache-dir --no-binary numpy
```

then go back to steps 1->3.